# Replacing text between span tags using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a text file that has multiple  tags and want to replace the text between these tags. I'm having trouble matching the text between the tags.

here is a sample of the tag

```
<span Property="name">Text-Sample-5</span>
```

What im using now is

```
preg_replace('/(<span Property="([name]*)">).*(<\/span)/i', 'New Text', $content);
```

Comment: [Have you tried using an XML parser instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/479156)

Comment: BTW, if you plan to keep the text you wrapped with `(...)`, use `'$1New Text$2'`